# Why doesn't my scene pop up when changing scenes (JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx

I have a simple button on the first scene that is supposed to lead to the second scene. When I click on the button, it changes scenes but only shows a blank screen. It works properly if I close the original stage and then show a new stage with the new scene on it, but I don't want to have to open a new window.

Here is my controller class:

```
public class TitleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button startButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    //When next/start/main buttons are clicked, transition scene
    public void transitionScenes() throws IOException{
        Stage stage;
        Stage newStage;
        Parent root;
        stage = (Stage) startButton.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Round_1.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application{

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root =   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Title_Screen.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args); 
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Round_1.fxml` is loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, it works in the alternate situation I stated above so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: When I use your code without constructing a `Scene` from a fxml file, but building it manually, e.g `new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("test")))` it works. So I thought there must be a problem with the fxml file

Comment: That would be changing `root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Round_1.fxml"));` to `root = new StackPane(new Label("test"));`, right? When I changed my code to that, the window closed after I clicked the button.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, when I switch the scene like that:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Button btnChangeScene = new Button("change scene");
        Button btnChangeSceneBack = new Button("change sceneBack");

        btnChangeScene.setOnAction(e -> {
            StackPane root = new StackPane(btnChangeSceneBack);
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnChangeScene.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(scene);
        });


        StackPane root = new StackPane(btnChangeScene);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

        btnChangeSceneBack.setOnAction(e -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! The only thing I had to do was add a stage.hide(); before I set the scene apparently...